# How to connect Java with oracle 8i database on local network

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle8i

I want to connect to Oracle 8i Database with java, where the database is on server on local network 10.3.1.1 at port

I have followed the example tutorial to make the connection from Oracle website

https://docs.oracle.com/html/A67296_01/im_examp.htm#997347

also I followed the instruction that specified here 
https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~chang/156/06oracle/jdbc.html

**You may need these details :**

- Oracle 8i Database port 1521
- Local Network Server Running on Windows Server 2003 ip 10.3.1.1
- java version "1.8.0_152" on machine on IP 10.3.1.2
- added classes12.zip file to build path

**This my Java Code:**

```
package com.oracle8i.testconnect;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBConnect {
    public Connection connection;

    public DBConnect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void connect() throws Exception {
        String connectString;
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connectString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.3.1.1:1521:dbname";
        System.out.println("Before DriverManager.getConnection");
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, "username", "password");
            System.out.println("Connection established");

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Exception inside connect(): " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DBConnect client = new DBConnect();

        System.out.println("beginning");
        try {
            client.connect();
            System.out.println("after Connected");

            client.connection.close();

            System.out.println("after close");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            try {
                System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
                client.connection.close();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println("Close Connection Exception : " + ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I get this error message:

```
beginning
Before DriverManager.getConnection
Exception inside connect(): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.<init>(T4C8TTIdty.java:491)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1434)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:711)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:558)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.oracle8i.testconnect.DBConnect.connect(DBConnect.java:19)
    at com.oracle8i.testconnect.DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:37)
after Connected
Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException
Close Connection Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.oracle8i.testconnect.DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:48)
```

---

I have looked on internet for solutions but nothing is working with me

These are my testing  and results:

- **Testing with wrong database name(SID)**

I have tested changing the dabase name (sid) with wrong name to check if its connected or not and thankfully it seems the connection to oracle almost correct because it response this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:711)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:558)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.oracle8i.testconnect.DBConnect.connect(DBConnect.java:19)
    at com.oracle8i.testconnect.DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:37)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:272)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
    ... 8 more
```

- **Checking The database Listener**

I've checked with the administrator the listener status and it is running (the system is running)

[image: database Listener]

- **Disable Firewall**

I have Disabled Firewall

[image]
[image]

Update 1: Adding  listener.ora content

```
# LISTENER.ORA Network Configuration File: D:\ORACLE\ORA8I\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      )
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = svrstn01)(PORT = 1521))
      )
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (PROTOCOL_STACK =
        (PRESENTATION = GIOP)
        (SESSION = RAW)
      )
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = svrstn01)(PORT = 2481))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\ORACLE\ORA8I)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = SITEEN)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\ORACLE\ORA8I)
      (SID_NAME = SITEEN)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Give your listener.ora in the C:\OraNT\network\admin or C:\Oracle\network\admin..

Comment: Your instance has SID SITEEN(OracleServiceSITEEN). Try another connection string.  connectString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.3.1.1:1521:SITEEN";

Comment: Regarding the listener.ora  I'll get the file content and update my question soon

Comment: @DmitryDemin I tried the new connection string I still get the same error , you simply capitalized SID

Comment: @DmitryDemin I've updated my question and added the content of listener.ora  file

Comment: Version 8.1.7(8i) was released in 2000.
Oracle client 11g and 12c can not connect to version 8i.
I think that java 1.8 can not directly connect to the 8i version.
Try installing Oracle client 9i, 10g. and connect using oracle client library
 `connectString = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@10.3.1.1:1521:SITEEN";`

Comment: What do you mean by "Try installing Oracle client 9i, 10g" is this on my machine or on server?  the system working on oracle 8i on the server.  What can I do from my machine on java , should I try another library ? please provide me the name of library

Comment: You could try an older version of the Oracle JDBC driver (eg 9.x or 10.x) if you can find it, but otherwise you are probably out of luck. Why do you even have a 17 year old Oracle version in use.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am using (classes12.zip)  Oracle8i 8.1.7.1  JDBC Drivers from oracle website http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc817-100207.html

Comment: @AhmadSaleh On the server, you do not need to install anything else. Install the instance client version 10.2.0.5 on the client PC and install sqlplus(Version 10.2.0.5 Instant Client Package - Basic: All files required to run OCI, OCCI, and JDBC-OCI applications instantclient-basic-win32-10.2.0.5.zip and instantclient-sqlplus-win32-10.2.0.5.zip ). Create tns_alias to the database in the tnsnames.ora file in the client instance directory. Check the connection to the database using `sqlplus user@tns_alias` .

Comment: Example tnsnames.ora

SITEEN =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.3.1.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = SITEEN)
    )
  )

Answer (score 0):

I installed a test site on a virtual infrastructure.

- Server: Windows 2003 SP2 32 bit
- Server: Oracle 8.1.7.0
- Client: windows 7 32 bit
- Client: java 1.8.0_73
- Client: Oracle client 9.2.0.1
- Client: classes12.jar from Oracle client 9.2.0.1 in C:\oracle\ora92\jdbc\lib

Tests with different versions of jdbc drivers:

- classes12.zip from Oracle Server 8.1.7.0 in Directory of C:\oracle\ora81\jdbc\lib
- classes12.jar from Oracle client 9.2.0.1 in C:\oracle\ora92\jdbc\lib
- http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/10205/classes12.jar
- http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/10205/ojdbc14.jar
- http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/111070/ojdbc6.jar
- http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/11204/ojdbc6.jar
- http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/121020/ojdbc7.jar
- http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/122010/ojdbc8.jar

Tests with different connectString:

- `connectString ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.89.251.123:1521:ORCL";`
- `connectString ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.89.251.123)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)))";`
- `connectString = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.89.251.123)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)))";`
- `connectString = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@ORCL8";`

Test connect to DB 8.1.7.0  SID=ORCL from Oracle Client 9.2.0.1

**C:\oracle\ora92\network>sqlplus scott@orcl8**

```
SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Dec 26 13:44:11 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.0.0 - Production
With the Partitioning option
JServer Release 8.1.7.0.0 - Production

connected> select * from v$version;



     ----------------------------------------------------------------
        Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.0.0 - Production
        PL/SQL Release 8.1.7.0.0 - Production
        CORE    8.1.7.0.0       Production
        TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 8.1.7.0.0 - Production
        NLSRTL Version 3.4.1.0.0 - Production

    Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
    connected>
```

Listener.ora

LISTENER.ORA Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\ora81\network\admin\listener.ora

Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC0))
      )
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.89.251.123)(PORT = 1521))
      )
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (PROTOCOL_STACK =
        (PRESENTATION = GIOP)
        (SESSION = RAW)
      )
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.89.251.123)(PORT = 2481))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\ora81)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ORCL)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\ora81)
      (SID_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )
```

TNSNAMES.ORA file from Oracle Client 9.2

```
### TNSNAMES.ORA Network Configuration File: 
### Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL8 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.89.251.123)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )
```

**This your Java Code:**  (thin jdbc->oracle server)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBConnect {
    public Connection connection;

    public DBConnect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void connect() throws Exception {
        String connectString;
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connectString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.89.251.123:1521:ORCL";
        System.out.println("Before DriverManager.getConnection");
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, "scott", "tiger");
            System.out.println("Connection established");

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Exception inside connect(): " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DBConnect client = new DBConnect();

    System.out.println("beginning");
    try {
        client.connect();
        System.out.println("after Connected");

        client.connection.close();

        System.out.println("after close");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        try {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
            client.connection.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Close Connection Exception : " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

**Test connection is Successfully !!!**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin>javac.exe  DBConnect.java


C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin>java -classpath  . DBConnect
beginning
Before DriverManager.getConnection
Connection established
after Connected
after close
```

Logging connections in the file listener.log file on Oracle Server c:\oracle\ora81\network\log\listener.log

```
26-DEC-2017 14:03:53 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.88.164.45)(PORT=54225)) * establish * ORCL * 0
```

**Change thin driver to oci (jdbc->oracle client library->oracle server)**

```
public void connect() throws Exception {
    String connectString;
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    connectString = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@ORCL8";
    System.out.println("Before DriverManager.getConnection");
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, "scott", "tiger");
        System.out.println("Connection established");

        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Exception inside connect(): " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin>java -classpath  . DBConnect
beginning
Before DriverManager.getConnection
Connection established
after Connected
after close
```

Logging connections in the file Listener.log file on Oracle Server c:\oracle\ora81\network\log\listener.log

```
26-DEC-2017 14:14:11 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.EXE)(HOST=IVC-PTK-DEMIN)(USER=DeminDV))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.88.164.45)(PORT=54424)) * establish * ORCL * 0
```

**I continued the tests with different versions of jdbc drivers.**
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

**Version 9.2.0.1, 8.1.7.0,  10.2.0.5 has successfully passed the test.**
Versions 11.1.0.5, 11.2.0.4,12.1.0.2, 12.2.0.1 did not pass the test.

```
**http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/10205/classes12.jar
classes12.jar (1,621,582 bytes) - for use with JDK 1.2 and JDK 1.3**



 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin>java -classpath  . DBConnect
    beginning
    Before DriverManager.getConnection
    Connection established
    after Connected
    after close

    http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/10205/ojdbc14.jar
    ojdbc14.jar (1,569,316 bytes) - classes for use with JDK 1.4 and 1.5
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin>java -classpath  . DBConnect
    beginning
    Before DriverManager.getConnection
    Connection established
    after Connected
    after close

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

**http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/111070/ojdbc6.jar
ojdbc6.jar (1,988,051 bytes) - Classes for use with JDK 1.6. It contains the JDBC** 

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin>java -classpath  . DBConnect
beginning
Before DriverManager.getConnection
Exception inside connect(): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1611)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at DBConnect.connect(DBConnect.java:20)
        at DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:38)
after Connected
Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException
Close Connection Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:49)


**http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/11204/ojdbc6.jar
ojdbc6.jar (2,739,670 bytes) - (SHA1 Checksum: a483a046eee2f404d864a6ff5b09dc0e1be3fe6c)
Certified with JDK 8, JDK 7 and JDK 6: It contains the JDBC driver** 

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin>java -classpath  . DBConnect
beginning
Before DriverManager.getConnection
Exception inside connect(): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.<init>(T4C8TTIdty.java:488)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1199)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at DBConnect.connect(DBConnect.java:20)
        at DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:38)
after Connected
Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException
Close Connection Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:49)

**http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/121020/ojdbc7.jar
ojdbc7.jar (3,397,734 bytes) - (SHA1 Checksum: a2348e4944956fac05235f7cd5d30bf872afb157)
Certified with JDK 7 and JDK 8; It contains the JDBC driver** 

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin>java -classpath  . DBConnect
beginning
Before DriverManager.getConnection
Exception inside connect(): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1611)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at DBConnect.connect(DBConnect.java:20)
        at DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:38)
after Connected
Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException
Close Connection Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:49)


**http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/122010/ojdbc8.jar
ojdbc8.jar (4,036,257 bytes) - (SHA1 Checksum: 60f439fd01536508df32658d0a416c49ac6f07fb) 
Certified with JDK 8; It contains the JDBC driver**

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin>java -classpath  . DBConnect
beginning
Before DriverManager.getConnection
Exception inside connect(): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1548)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at DBConnect.connect(DBConnect.java:20)
        at DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:38)
after Connected
Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException
Close Connection Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:49)
```

Comment: I'v downloaded instant client and sqlplus 10.2   as you mentioned on your comment above (before editing) and connect to server database successfully with sqlplus using this command -- sqlplus username/password@//10.3.1.1/DBNAME    -- but i couldn't find TNSNAMES.ORA fon the downloaded files

Comment: on java I replaced the previous classes12.zip with classes12.jar  that downloaded with instant client 10.2,  but still I get this error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4`  while if I change the DBName I get  `java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`

Comment: Please provide me with Oracle client 9.2.0.1 link I couldnt find it on oracle download page where older version available is Version 10.2.0.2  neither on Oracle edelivery page

Comment: @AhmadSaleh you can donwload classes12.zip or Classes111.zip in your Oracle Server 8.1.7 in directory $ORACLE_HOME\jdbc\lib, but classes12.zip http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/10205/classes12.jar
classes12.jar (1,621,582 bytes) - for use with JDK 1.2 and JDK 1.3 work is good.

Comment: @AhmadSaleh You must create a file tnsnames.ora in directory instant clent   or  use a special connect  string `connectString ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.89.251.123)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)))";
connectString = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.89.251.123)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)))";`